# C++ stack surrounding array is corrupted

Tags: c++, stack, corrupt

I have tried to read a few different posts about **the stack surrounding a variable is corrupted** but am having trouble connecting the answers to my code. I am wondering why I keep getting an error message that says the stack surrounding **scoreArray** is corrupted. I have tried using multiple variables to increment the location on the array. I know the code is not well written, but I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand why i would receive that message.

Thank you so much.

```
double sum = 0.0; 

double SumFunction(double printArray[]);

int i = 0;
int j = 0; 

const int SIZE = 4;

void main()
{
    double input = 0.0;
    vector<double> scores;
    double scoreArray[SIZE];

    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a decimal value: ";
        cin >> input;

        scores.push_back(input);
    } while (scores.size() <= SIZE);

    do
    {
        int z = 0; 
        scoreArray[i] = scores[z];
        i++;
        z++;
    } while (i <= SIZE); 
    SumFunction(scoreArray);

    cout << sum; 

    system("PAUSE"); 
}

double SumFunction(double printArray[])
{
    do
    {
        sum += printArray[j]; 
        j++; 
    } while (j <= SIZE); 

    return sum; 
}
```

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C++.  I suggest you turn on the warnings in your compiler.

Comment: `while (i <= SIZE);` loops one cycle too much! Change to `while (i < SIZE);` analogous in other places you compare with `<= SIZE`.

Comment: You will *almost never* want do/while loops. They're incredibly specific and very rarely useful (e.g. for `next_permutation`). Almost every loop is a `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

Because:

```
/*(1)*/ } while (scores.size() <= SIZE);
/*(2)*/ } while (i <= SIZE); 
/*(3)*/ } while (j <= SIZE);
```

should be:

```
/*(1)*/ } while (scores.size() < SIZE);
/*(2)*/ } while (i < SIZE); 
/*(3)*/ } while (j < SIZE);
```

since your `do...while` loops enter another iteration when the index already exceeds alloted space of `scoreArray`.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much. I was able to get it to work. I really appreciate all the good advice. I will try using for loops instead as well.